# Display error CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.7

CakePHP is displaying `An Internal Error Has Occurred.` but doesn't provide me with any information at all about it.

Even when I through an exception like this I still getting the same message `An Internal Error Has Occurred.`

```
throw new Exception("Error connecting with the database.");
```

I'm already using `Configure::write('debug', 2);` in my core.php

My `php.ini` contains `display_errors = On` and I even tried using the following in the controller's action:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Check your php and application log files.

Comment: just check your `tmp/log/error.log`

Comment: @AD7six far from ideal. I want to see the message when I'm on development... Why should CakePHP hide it in development ?

Comment: @Alvaro I'm not providing you an answer (comments aren't for answers) - I'm asking you to clarify the question. It's unclear atm whether you are looking at a php generated error at all. Also very-early errors can't be captured by the framework, looking at the _actual_ problem will likely indicate why your efforts so far haven't worked.

Comment: output the config for `debug` in a view where you expect the error to be and see if its being over-ridden somewhere and not at 2

Answer (score 1):

In order to **Enable errors** in cakephp.

Edit `config/app.php`

change this

```
'debug' => filter_var(env('DEBUG', false), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN),
```

to this

```
'debug' => filter_var(env('DEBUG', true), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN),
```

That's it now all errors will be shown.